# How to determine the number of similar bits?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I need to compare two numbers and look for similarities in more significant bits. I'm trying to determine the number of least significant bits that differ.

```
10111000
10111011
```

184 and 187 require an offset of two, because only two least significant bits differ.

```
10111011
11111011
```

187 and 251 require an offset of seven, because the seventh least significant bit differs.

My first idea was to XOR the numbers together, then bit-shift right until the number equaled zero. I feel like there is a better bit-wise solution to this that doesn't involve loops, but I haven't done enough bit-twiddling of my own to come up with it.

The solution needs to work for any 64 bits, as my numbers are being stored as `UInt64`. This is being written in C#, but the solution is most likely a language agnostic one.

---

```
11101101
11010101
```

Would need an offset of 6 bits. I'm trying to find how many similar bits I can take off the top.

Comment: Good problem to solve, but it's not quite clear what the result should be in case of, for example, numbers 11101101 and 11010101 (i.e. there's a difference on multiple positions).

Comment: with a shift by 1 in a loop you even don't need to xor them - instead of comparing to 0 you may shift until they are equal

Comment: @Eugene - I added your example. @doc - True, but it's still what I'm trying to avoid. I just knew XORing was the right direction..

Comment: Interesting thing is that in x86 assembler your approach with XOR is coded very effectively and can hardly be bitten (unless they introduce a special command such as "get position of 1 in a byte), while in C# it would probably need much more code.

Comment: @Eugene: I'm not sure what you mean by the part in parentheses. In x86 assembly, if we require at least a 386, the problem reduces to `xor` + `bsr`, no? And starting with Pentium II, that should only take a low constant number of clock cycles.

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig That was it, I stand corrected. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TO_L(s) (strtol((s), NULL, 16))

int tsb(unsigned long xa, unsigned long xb) {
  unsigned long v = xa ^ xb;
  static const unsigned long b[] = {
    0x2, 0xC, 0xF0, 0xFF00, 0xFFFF0000L, 0xFFFFffff00000000L
  };
  static const unsigned int S[]  = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 };
  unsigned int r = 0;

#define STEP(i)   \
  if(v & b[i]) {  \
    int t = S[i]; \
    v >>= t;      \
    r  |= t;      \
  }
  STEP(5)
  STEP(4)
  STEP(3)
  STEP(2)
  STEP(1)
  STEP(0)
  return r;
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  return printf("%d\n", tsb(TO_L(av[1]), TO_L(av[2]))), 0;
}
```

I think this implements your algorithm and it's very fast, needing only 6 steps. See this *[great source of bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious)*.

```
so ross$ ./a.out 1f f
4
so ross$ ./a.out 471234abcdabcd 981234abcdabcd
55
so ross$ ./a.out 1deadbeef 7feedface
34
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've already spotted the main trick; r = x XOR y, then find the highest bit in r. There is a bunch of different way to solve [that problem here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog). The fastest does it in O(n) operations by splitting r in half and checking if the upper part is zero. If you are doing this on a fixed number of bits (you said 64) then unroll the loops to get a series of tests :

```
pos = 0
r = x XOR y
if r>>32 == 0 :
   r = r & 2^32-1
else
   pos += 32
   r = r>>32
if r>>16 == 0 :
   r = r & 2^16-1
else
   pos += 16
   r = r>16
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
floor( log(184 ^ 187) / log(2) ) + 1
```

No loop, but might not been faster, because log in a costly operation. You should test it, and compare to a simple loop with bit-shifting.

**Sometimes a (well-coded) loop is faster than no-loop**, especially if you have at most 64 iterations and often less.

---

**More efficient version of my code :**

Pre-compute

```
double Ilog2 = 1 / log(2);
```

and then each time you need it

```
floor( log(184 ^ 187) * ILog2 ) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a O(log(n)) loop to find the highest set bit pretty easily:

```
int findHighestSetBit(unsigned long long x) {
    int rv = 0;
    if (x == 0)
        return -1;  // no set bits
    for (int shift = 32; shift > 0; shift >>= 1) {
        if (x >> shift) {
            rv += shift;
            x >>= shift;
        }
    }
    return rv+1; // number least significant bit as '1' rather than '0'
}
```

if this is too slow, you can manually unroll the loop 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first you have to do it for 8 bit numbers.
the fastest way is a 256 bytes lookup table with precompiled values:

```
static unsigned char highest_bit_num_LUT[256] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, etc }; // precomputed

unsigned diff = (unsigned)a ^ (unsigned)b; // sure you need XOR and not MINUS?
unsigned highest_bit_num = highest_bit_num_LUT[diff & 0xff];
```

now extending it for higher bit counts:

```
static unsigned char highest_bit_num_LUT[256] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, etc }; // precomputed
unsigned diff = (unsigned)a ^ (unsigned)b; // sure you need XOR and not MINUS?
unsigned highest_bit_num = 0;
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)    
    if (diff >> ( i*8) ){ // found most significant non-zero byte
        highest_bit_num = i*8 + highest_bit_num_LUT[diff >> (i*8)];
        break;
    }
```

so now we have at most 8 iterations.

EDIT: it would be faster to use DigitalRoss idea for first 3 iterations, and then to use the LUT.